# value reduceByKey is not a member of List[(String, Int)]

Tags: scala

My code is below but it produces the error in the title. Can anyone explain what is going on?

```
val firstFileFlatten = scala.io.Source
    .fromFile(firstFile)
    .getLines
    .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
    .toList

val filteredWordsFirstFile = firstFileFlatten
    .filter(!stopWords.contains(_))

val mapreduceFirstFile = filteredWordsFirstFile
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey((v1,v2) => v1 + v2)
```

Comment: Any reason why you tagged it apache-spark?

Comment: its a Spark project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reduceByKey` does not exist in plain scala. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9064) for more details.

A work arround would be do do it like this:

```
listOfPairs
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map{ case (key, list) => key -> list.map(_._2).reduce(_+_) }
```

Comment: Is it better to work with RDDs or normal lists? Because later on I want to do a "join" operation and that apparently does not work with maps/lists...

Comment: It mostly depends on the amount of data you have. In scala you have much more flexibility. In Spark, you have parallelism but also some overhead (mostly the cost of network communications but not only). If you want to join that data with a RDD, you can either parallelize it after the transformations (`sc.parallelize(list)`) or before and use the spark API. Also, if you do not have that much data, I recommend you try a broadcast join.

Answer (score 2):

You work with standard Scala collections, not with RDD. There is no method `reduceByKey` there, use `reduce`. Or work with RDD via Spark, then you can use `reduceByKey`.

https://dzone.com/articles/wordcount-with-spark-and-scala

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/List.html